# C# extract delegate data to out side of the Action context

Tags: c#, delegates

I am invoking a `Action<CalcResult>` deligate and I need to use `CalcResult` value out side of the Action context.
(please see the comments in the function)

```
public function CalcResult Run(){
  var context = new Context();
  context.CalcResultHandler = (CalcResult calcResult) =>{ };
  Execute(context);

  //here I need to return the var `calcResult` from above
  return calcResult; // this wont compile obviously 
}


public abstract class BaseExecutionContext
{
   public Action<CalcResult> CalcResultHandler { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is the handler actually called? If it happens within `Execute` you could just let this method return the instance.

Answer (score 0):

If the delegate is executed within your `Execute`-method you should set its return-type to `CalcResult` instead of messing around with the delegate to set the variable:

```
CalcResult Execute(context)
{
    ...
    CalcResult result = ...
    contect.CalcResultHanlder(result);
    return result;
}
```

Now use the methods return-value:

```
public CalcResult Run()
{
    var context = new Context();
    context.CalcResultHandler = (CalcResult calcResult) =>{ };
    return Execute(context);
}
```